# Multiple Clickable Areas in ListItem

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a list that is organized as follows: 
`CheckBox`, 
`ImageButton`,
`LinearLayout{ TextView title, TextView Subtitle}`

What I am trying to do is to have three separate clickable areas of the `ListItem`: the checkbox should be `checkable`, `ImageButton`, and the actual list item itself. The checkbox is hidden by default, but can be made visible when a certain button on the list's header is pressed (ie `SELECT`). I just want a way to select multiple items from the list, and I am not irreversibly set on using hidden checkboxes- if there is a way to do this that would be easier, I would be happy to hear the alternative.

Here is the relevant snippet of my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    final T t = list.get(position);
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.folder_list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_folder_item);
        holder.subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
        holder.eye = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_vis_button);
        holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(t.getName());
    holder.subtitle.setText(t.getDescription());// = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
    return convertView;
}
```

And the XML is as follows. As you can see, I have made the individual list items clickable but unfocassable, as recommended in posts I have read about this very problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"        
    android:focusable="false"/>   
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/folder_vis_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/open_eyeball" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/folder_vis_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_folder_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Clicking on the list item is handled, if I convert the listitem to actually use on of the built in listitems such as `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. 
However, when I use my own layout, I cannot get click events on the list item itself, just on the image button. 
I have tried inflating the view in a different way (int resource, ViewGroup root) ... I have tried working just with the imagebutton, or just with the checkbox, using an imageview instead of an imagebutton, with little in terms of success. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: why you don't handle all click in `getView` method?

Comment: I have tried that. Clicks on individual items- the CheckBox, and the ImageButton are successful. This however, doesn't solve the central problem of the click on the list item itself. I have removed this handles for the sake of brevity of the question. @shayanpourvatan

Comment: did you write `convertView.setonclick....()` too? what is the problem with that?

Comment: I didn't write that. The adapter is used in a ListFragment. I am using the built in onListItemClick to handle click events on the list items. Can this work?

Comment: use that code instead of `onListItemClick` and check result

Comment: The result is interesting. Some clicks are registered, but specifically clicks on areas that are not covered by anything else- that is not by the textboxes, checkbox or anything whatsoever. This is definitely a step forward. Thank you, @shayanpourvatan